# Using JNI in flink YARN cluster jobs

Tags: java, scala, hadoop, apache-flink

I have an application that dispatches Apache Flink jobs to an AWS Elastic MapReduce YARN cluster through the `RemoteExecutionEnvironment` scala API.

These jobs use the JNI to run part of their calculations through a C library. During development I just put a `System.loadLibrary()` call in a `RichCrossFunction`'s `open()` method to load this JNI library. This worked fine in a `LocalExecutionEnvironment`.

Now that I'm moving to a `RemoteExecutionEnvironment` this no longer seems to work. It looks like Flink is using a new `ClassLoader` every time it dispatches a job and I am getting `Native library already loaded in another classloader` errors on the calculation nodes.

Some googling informed me that this is a common issue with Tomcat applications and a solution is available in the Tomcat FAQ: http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/HowTo#I.27m_encountering_classloader_problems_when_using_JNI_under_Tomcat

Is there a similar solution available for Flink or YARN?

Additionally, is it possible to avoid resubmitting the JAR every time a job is queued? I'm always using the same jar on this cluster, so it's unnecessary overhead...

Answer (score 3):

I fixed the issue by calling `loadLibrary` in a static initializer in my JNI jar, then dropping my JNI jar in Flink's `/lib` folder, similar to the pattern in the Tomcat link above.

It is automatically replicated to the Flink TaskManagers by the `yarn-session.sh` startup procedure. This allowed me to circumvent the `ClassLoader` segregation in the same way you would do with Tomcat.

I'm using Maven, so I prevented the JNI jar from being included in my uberjar using maven-shade-plugin.

I still don't know if this is the best way, since the flink manual discourages using the `/lib` folder because it doesn't respect their ClassLoader management (https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.0/apis/cluster_execution.html), but that's exactly what I wanted.

Maybe another way would have been to use a NativeLoader pattern and create a separate temp file for every ClassLoader, but that would create a bunch of duplicate native libraries and this method works for me.